# Is it necessary to specify version of a maven plugin in pom?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I am using NetBeans for development and it has built-in menu feature that allows us to add `maven-checkstyle-plugin` in the pom for code formatting . However, when you click on that menu it add the following piece of code in the pom automatically but without the `<version>` information. Now my IDE keeps on complaining with a small hint message in the margin saying that the 'version' tag is missing. My question is:
Does all plugins added has to have a `<version>` tag in the pom?

## pom.xml

```
 <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>config/sun_checks.xml</configLocation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
```

Comment: It's explained below in @dimasiu answer. Summarized: If you want your build to be reproducible, you need to specify the plugin versions. For example if a incompatible plugin change was pushed to Maven Central you don't want your build to mysteriously stop working.

Answer (score 6):

It is not necessary, but highly recommended to use the version tag.

> When a plugin was invoked without an explicit version given in the POM
>   or on the command line, Maven 2.x used to pick the latest version
>   available where the latest version could either be a release or a
>   snapshot. For the sake of stability, Maven 3.x prefers the latest
>   release version over the latest snapshot version.
>
> Given the threat of non-reproducible builds imposed by automatic
>   plugin version resolution, this feature is scheduled for removal as
>   far as plugin declarations in the POM are concerned. Users of Maven
>   3.x will find it output a warning when missing plugin versions are detected to encourage the addition of plugin versions to the POM or
>   one of its parent POMs. The Enforcer rule requirePluginVersions can be
>   used additionally check for missing plugin versions in the POM.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+3.x+Compatibility+Notes